# Finalizar compra del carrito por Whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, botón, whatsapp

Estoy haciendo una tienda online con JS y me gustaria que el boton de Finalizar Compra te redirija a Whatsapp con el listado de los productos y el total de la compra. (Helados Daniel tiene ese formato) pero no se como hacerlo. Alguien podria ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Comment: Quizá lo puedes hacer con el método `location.href`, te puede servir para redirigir el link de la api de whatsaap y modificar la url con variables.

Comment: Te dejaré en las respuestas una posible solución y su explicación.

Answer (score 1):

**Posible solución:**

```js
var products= ['zapato', 'mesa', 'silla']
window.location.href = 'https://wa.me/50212345678/?text=' + ' ' + products[0] + ' ' + products[1] + ' ' + products[2]
```

**Explicación:**
En una variable llamada `products` almacené 3 productos, zapato, mesa y silla, luego con el método `location.href` lo que hago es que al cargar la página me redireccione a la url que le especifiqué (En este caso la url de Whatsaap) y le concateno los productos, luego me redirecciona a dicha página para empezar a chatear con el número asignado y en el chat aparecerán los 3 productos.

**Si lo quisieras más dinámico lo puedes hacer algo así:**

```js
function iniciarChatear(){
        var products= ['zapato', 'mesa', 'silla']
        window.location.href = 'https://wa.me/50212345678/?text=' + ' ' + products[0] + ' ' + products[1] + ' ' + products[2]
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="chatear" onclick="iniciarChatear();">Confirmar compra</button>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.